# How to add a colored panel to a page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, page-layout, sitepages

I want to add a colored and bordered panel to a SharePoint Online page to highlight some rich text. I am using the modern experience.

In Confluence this is done by editing a page and adding the 'Insert Panel' macro, but I can find no similar Web Part or capability in SharePoint. I am not a developer, so want to avoid using CSS/HTML code if possible, but I have spent hours on this so far so maybe that is my only option.

It seems odd that such a basic design feature is not available out-of-the-box.

Comment: Are you using modern experience pages or classic experience pages? Did you already added "some rich text" to page or you need solution to add text as well as colored border to the text?

Comment: @GaneshSanap I am using the modern experience.  Ideally, I would add the colored and bordered panel, then enter the text into it....but adding the text first would OK too.

Comment: Check my answer given below. This is the best solution you can use on modern experience without any custom solution, CSS/JS, 3rd party solutions.

Comment: Check my answer given below. This is the best solution you can use on modern experience without any custom solution, CSS/JS, 3rd party solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following steps:

1. Go to your SharePoint online modern experience page
2. Click **Edit** option from top right corner to open page in edit mode
3. Add [Text web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/add-text-tables-and-images-to-your-page-with-the-text-web-part-729c0aa1-bc0d-41e3-9cde-c60533f2c801) to the page
4. Insert a new table in the text web part using toolbar options
5. Remove extra rows and columns to keep only one table cell
6. Select the colored table style from toolbar options
7. Add text message inside the table cell as per your requirements.

[image]

**Output**:

[image]